# how to change typedef struct declaration into a using alias struct?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, using

my struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int foo;
  char key;
} myStruct;
```

and I would like to change it to

```
using struct myStruct = {
      int foo;
      char key;
    } myStruct;
```

but it seems that something is wrong with it

Comment: `struct myStruct{ int foo; char key; };`

Comment: That's the simple implementation but I need the using keyword in my app

Comment: `struct actualStruct{ int foo; char key; }; using myStruct = actualStruct;`

Comment: Why?  Is it an assignment requirement?  Unlike C, in C++ the name of class does not need to be decorated with `struct` in order to use it so your class name is the type name.

Comment: it was more of a requirement for actual app.

Comment: You could have `using myStruct = struct {...};` but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @AlexButane It's a requirement that doesn't make any sense. At least in this case.

Comment: @DanielLangr to replace all typedef's to a newer method

Comment: The "newer method" in C++ is just to drop the `typedef` from the declaration of the `struct`.

Comment: @AlexButane in C++ if you have `struct X {...}`. `X` is already a type. No need for typedef like you do in C.

Comment: @AdrianMole Newer is relative, it has been the C++ way almost as long as I can remember. I associate that style with 100% "C"

Comment: why do you want an alias? Why not simply give a name to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: @AlexButane So, you want to replace something that doesn't make sense with something else that doesn't make sense as well? This doesn't make sense at all ;)

Comment: @everyone you are right but if I was requested to change the typedef's to using's I need to find a way to do it.

Comment: @NathanOliver you want to turn that into an actual answer, so people can vote for it?

Comment: @AlexButane Maybe, you should ask the people who asked you why they insist on using `using`.

Comment: @Alex - When you were asked to replace `typedef` by `using`, perhaps your manager didn't think anyone would ever have used `typedef struct` in C++?

Comment: OP is confusing the spirit of the task with the actual way people write C++. And this shouldn't be a manual task anyway. I'm pretty sure clang-tidy has checks for both of these situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can replace

```
typedef struct
{
  int foo;
  char key;
} myStruct;
```

by

```
using myStruct = struct
{
  int foo;
  char key;
};
```

But it doesn't make any sense, and you will just confuse readers or possible maintainers of the code.

The established way to go is:

```
struct myStruct
{
  int foo;
  char key;
};
```

Comment: using myStruct = struct _myStruct 
{
  int foo;
  char key;
}; what does this decleration mean?

Comment: @AlexButane Type alias declaration; see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias.